# Android: how to delete recurring events

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-event

I'm building a calendar provider that is synchronizing calendar events with server. When I try to delete an event it is working fine if the event is non-recurring. When I try to delete recurring event it does not show me any error or anything, but all the events from the calendar disappear. The log doesn't show me any error after that, it gives me all standard logs only, but nothing appears on the calendar after that. Here is my code that I use for deleting all the events (recurring and non-recurring):

```
resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, id), null, null);
```

where `resolver` is the `ContentResolver` and `id` is the id of the event in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. The above code is working fine for deleting events

Comment: What was the reason why it was causing all your events to disappear from the Calendar?  The same thing is happening to me.  I try to delete a recurring event either with `resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, id), null, null);` or `resolver.delete(Events.CONTENT_URI, Events._ID + " =?", new String[]{id});`, but it causes ALL the events on my calendar to disappear.  I checked the database and all the events are there, but the Instances table is empty.  What is causing this?

Comment: I don't really remember what as the problem. I think it was something with the id. Make sure that your id is the id of the event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I verified that the id is the id of the event, but I still got the same result.  When you were deleting, were you passing the `CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` as `true`?

Comment: No, I only have this `Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, id); resolver.delete(uri, null, null);`

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Any help on how you got around it would be appreciated. Thanks!